# Update specific value in Pandas DF using ['index', 'column_name'] coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update/modify a value in my Dataframe based on the index and a column name

I know I can find the actual value in a combination of row columns by

```
df.at[53, 'last_date_used']
```

in this case it gives me a `nan` value because there is actually nothing in there, but I would like to change/update that number for this new value:

```
$>>> today = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
'07/12/2020'
```

I tried:

```
today = df.at[53, 'last_date_used']
```

But the result is still `nan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have assignment backwards. An expression like `item = value` will set `item` to `value`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "last_date_used": None}, {"id": 2, "last_date_used": "07/30/2020"}])
df

    id  last_date_used
0   1   None
1   2   07/30/2020

df.at[0, "last_date_used"] = "07/12/2020"
df

    id  last_date_used
0   1   07/12/2020
1   2   07/30/2020
```